# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repositories.UserDAO] is defined

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC and Hibernate.

I have a main Controller that deals with all requests. I have written a a test in order to test mySQL database connection with a simple example.

```
@Controller
```

public class HomeController{

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


@RequestMapping(value = "/db")
public void dbTester(){

    User tester = new User();
    tester.setName("Ytesting");
    tester.setToken("ranodm");
    tester.setNumber("123456789");

    UserDAO userRepo = applicationContext.getBean(UserDAO.class);
    userRepo.save(tester);

}
```

When getting to the Second last line it throws this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repositories.UserDAO] is defined
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [repositories.UserDAO] is defined
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:374)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:371)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:334)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1088)
    com.controllers.HomeController.dbTester(HomeController.java:89)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

I cannot figure out what the problem is.

my applicationContext looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<!-- This will define where the Dispatcher will look for a controller
 that has a Request mapping of "/" -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.controllers"/>

<!-- This sets the default home page-->
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="/login"/>
<!-- Sets the default path for all the Resources -->
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/"/>
```

and my UserDOAImpl:

```
@Repository
```

public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


@Transactional
public User getByID(int id) {
    return null;
}

@Transactional
public void save(User u) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(u);
}
```

}

I just can't seem to figure out what the problem is

**EDIT:**

This is my ApplictionContext xml:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="models"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="repositories"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="services"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="controllers"/>

<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/kroc_db_1"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="yossi"/>
</bean>



<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>models.entities.CardInfo</value>
            <value>models.entities.Vendor</value>
            <value>models.entities.User</value>
            <value>models.entities.Card</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager"
      p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory"/>
```

Comment: autowire the dao directly not the applicationContext

Comment: Correct the component can. it should include the package where the dao is located